# CSS: Problems when using object-fit and transform together on webkit

Tags: css, webkit, transform, scale

I'm trying to use both the css property `object-fit: cover` on an `img` element to have my image filling its containing `div` and `transform: scale(xx)` to have the image zooming out on hover.

Here is a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96kbuncq/
Edit: sample with real images: https://jsfiddle.net/96kbuncq/3/

HTML:

```
<div>
   <div class="category">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x950&text=1200x950+-+Category+1+-" />
   </div>
   <div class="category">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x950&text=1200x950+-+Category+2+-" />
   </div>
   <div class="category">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x950&text=1200x950+-+Category+3+-" />
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.....

div.category img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

/* Transformations */

div.category img {
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  transform: /*translateZ(0)*/ scale(1.12);
}

div.category:hover img {
  transform: /*translateZ(0)*/ scale(1);
}
```

This is working fine in Firefox but in Chrome and Opera I have the following problems:

- When hovering the first `div`, the two others are also affected (and when hovering the second one, the third one is also affected),
- When hovering a `div`, the image inside is first entirely displayed (we can see the whole image stretched to fit inside the `div`) before being correctly zoomed out and "covering" the `div`.

I don't know how to solve those problems.

About the first problem (affected siblings), I've found other answers saying to use `translateZ(0)` but when I add this the `object-fit: cover` is not working anymore (the whole image is stretched to fit inside the `div`).

Any ideas how to make this work in Chrome ? (Both the `object-fit` and `transform` are working as expected when used without the other.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After testing it seems that `backface-visibility`, `translateZ`, and `translate3d` which are required to prevent the transform flicker, break `object-fit` and `background-size`. If your goal is to center the image then you can use `position: absolute` and `translate` like in the example below.

```css
div.category {
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.12); /* order is important here*/
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
}
div.category:hover img {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="category">
        <img src="http://www.4freephotos.com/images/batch/Elephant-dusting674.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <img src="http://www.4freephotos.com/images/batch/Bananas-and-kiwi-221.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x950&text=1200x950+-+Category+3+-" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/r1s1rtLk/4/**

Comment: With this I have the same problem as when using translateZ(0), object-fit doesn't work and the image is stretched. Maybe we better see the problem with real images: https://jsfiddle.net/96kbuncq/2/

Comment: Thanks. This works well in Chrome but in Firefox the images are not vertically centered. Do you know how to make it work also in Firefox ?

Comment: You can use this approach if you don't need to solve the specific issue for which object-fit was created. That is, that you don't know in advance if the image has to be adjusted related to width or related to height.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an extra layer, with class wrap, and use this to make the zoom effect

Your styles are the same, but reasigned

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

div.category {
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.wrap {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

div.category .wrap img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

/* Transformations */

div.category .wrap {
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    transform:  scale(1.12);
}

div.category:hover .wrap {
    transform:  scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="category">
        <div class="wrap">
        <img src="http://www.4freephotos.com/images/batch/Elephant-dusting674.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <div class="wrap">
        <img src="http://www.4freephotos.com/images/batch/Bananas-and-kiwi-221.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
        <div class="wrap">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x950&text=1200x950+-+Category+3+-" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it works in Chrome but in Firefox the image is stretched when hovering instead of just zooming out. Do you know how to make it work both in Firefox and Chrome ?

Comment: Sorry, haven't been able to find a workaround for both. But both are browser bugs, so this will probably get fixed in future versions. Would it be ok to use a div with background-image instead of img ?

Comment: Thank you anyway. I didn't want to use background-image and the other solution works for me so I will use that before object-fit is better supported.