# Distortion is present when transitioning img with CSS object fit

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I checked it in Chrome and Firefox and in both browsers when I hover over the image, the transition seems to forget that the `object-fit` rule is applied.

Is this a bug or is there something wrong?

**EDIT: I found it looks good if I put the img inside a `div` and animate that `div`. But I wouldn't like to modify my html for css reasons.**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
figure {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
  <img src="http://www.fondox.net/wallpapers/un-gato-bebe-433.jpg" alt="" />
</figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set height as auto:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
figure {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
  <img src="http://www.fondox.net/wallpapers/un-gato-bebe-433.jpg" alt="" />
</figure>
```

Comment: Sorry but if you do this, object-fit doesn't work, even if you don't notice it. The image should be centered and it isnt...

Comment: Indeed, i didn't noticed this. So maybe you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006545/css-problems-when-using-object-fit-and-transform-together-on-webkit hope it could help.