# Specific CSS making image flash on and off in Wordpress Loop in Safari

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress loop which I'm using to display recent blog posts on my homepage. Heres the page: http://webserver-meetandengage-com.m11e.net and if you scroll down to recent posts you will see the issue... which his a strange one!

The images are flashing on and off!! Here\s the loop:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="card-columns">
<?php 
   // the query
   $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'cat' => '-14',
     'posts_per_page' => 3,
   )); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">


            <div class="blog-thumb-container-home">

                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>

    </a>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
  <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

I've gone through the code bit by bit and it seems to be this part of the CSS that's making it happen as when I disable it, it stops! Heres the CSS:

```
.blog-thumb-container-home {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 208px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blog-thumb-container-home img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

More specifically, when the `position: absolute;` and `-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` are turned off, the image stops flashing.

Strangely this only seems to happen in Safari! It doesnt flash in Chrome or Firefox and I have tried disabling all my Safari Extensions...

I'm also using a shortcode to pull this loop in as its inside an Elementor page builder block.

Can anyone think of a reason these bits of CSS might be making the image display and not display every second or so? Thanks a lo for looking!! :)

Comment: Not flashing for me on Chrome.

Comment: Not flashing for me either

Comment: Oh ok... I'm using Safari... That's really strange...

Comment: Ive just updated to be Safari specific - thanks for the heads up! :)

Comment: Take a look at this question --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006545/css-problems-when-using-object-fit-and-transform-together-on-webkit

Comment: Thanks @sol - thats interesting - I've managed to get it to stop flashing but now I can't control the size of the image for some reason! :-/